# Convolution of a conditional PDF with itself

Tags: conditional-probability, convolution

Let's say that $x$ is a random variable which follows a conditional probability density function $f(x|N)$, where $N$ is an integer parameter. If the functional form of $f(x|N=1)$ is known, then one can calculate the convolution of this $f(x|N=1)$ with itself like the following:

$\int_{0}^{a}f(y|N=1)f(a-y|N=n-1)dy$.

Then is this equal to the probability density function of $x$ given $N=n$, so $f(x|N=n)$? If so, could you please show a proof or explain qualitatively why the two terms are identical?

For the people who wonder where the formula was seen, this is [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.12635.pdf) showing such a formula. Please see Equation (5).